# Command to display first few and last few lines of a file

Tags: text-processing, logs, tail, cat, head

I have a file with many rows, and each row has a timestamp at the starting, like

```
[Thread-3] (21/09/12 06:17:38:672) logged message from code.....
```

So, I frequently check 2 things from this log file.

1. First few rows, that has the global conditions and start time is also given.
2. Last few rows, that has the exit status with some other info.

Is there any quick handy single command that could let me display just the first and last few lines of a file?

Comment: What's global conditions, and doesn't `head and tail` works for you?

Comment: That is the part of my log file. I was trying to be elaborative. You can ignore that.

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me. If you want more convenience, make it into a shell function (even an alias might do).

Comment: @vonbrand Problem is that I don't know `N`

Comment: @Bernhard, I'm no `sed(1)` expert, but there are ways of stashing stuff away for later use with it. Maybe it pays off to look in there. OTOH, I'd probably whip up a Perl (or whatever) script to do it if used frequently, as I'm more familiar with that.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the hint, didn't find that one. Only the mentioned solutions don't work with a pipe. E.g. if I do `./lotsofoutput | first_last -` it will only perform the `head` operation.

Comment: One thing is that it doesn't *need* to be convenient and easy to remember, you just have to put it in your `.bashrc`, or as a script in `$HOME/bin`, etc.

Comment: If the input is a pipe, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66408/combing-head-and-tail-in-a-single-call-via-pipe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `sed` or `awk` to make it with one command. However you'll loose at speed, cause `sed` and `awk` will need to run through the whole file anyway.
From a speed point of view it's much better to make a function or every time to combination of `tail` + `head`. This does have the downside of not working if the input is a pipe, however you can use proccess substitution, in case your shell supports it (look at example below).

```
first_last () {
    head -n 10 -- "$1"
    tail -n 10 -- "$1"
}
```

and just launch it as

```
first_last "/path/to/file_to_process"
```

to proceed with process substitution (bash, zsh, ksh like shells only):

```
first_last <( command )
```

ps. you can even add a `grep` to check if your "global conditions" exist.

Comment: `-n 10` is the default, no?

Comment: @l0b0 yes, it's default. `-n 10` is not necessary here.

Answer (score 22):

@rush is right about using head + tail being more efficient for large files, but for small files (< 20 lines), some lines may be output twice.

```
{ head; tail;} < /path/to/file
```

would be equally efficient, but wouldn't have the problem above.

Comment: In contrast to rushs solution, this does not work in a POSIX shell.

Comment: @Marco Huh? Only POSIX constructs are used here. What do you see going wrong?

Comment: @Gilles I missed the space: `{head; tail;} < file` works in zsh but fails in sh. `{ head; tail;} < file` always works. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Marco, if there were problems with that, it would be with `head`, not the shell. POSIX requires `head` to leave the cursor in the file just past those 10 lines for regular files. A problem could arise for non-POSIX `head` implementations (very old versions of GNU head used to be non-conformant in that instance, but we're talking decades) or if the file is not seekable (like named pipe or socket, but then the other solution would have the same problem).

Comment: For multiple files we `for f in *; do { head; tail;} < $f; done`

Comment: How would you run this with sudo?

Comment: @FCTW, `sudo sh -c '{ head; tail;} < /path/to/file'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  TYVM!  Long ago as I asked this, I've probably learned enough at my job to have figured this out, but your response is FANTASTIC!  :-)

Answer (score 10):

The `{ head; tail; }` solution wouldn't work on pipes (or sockets or any other non-seekable files) because `head` could consume too much data as it reads by blocks and can't seek back on a pipe potentially leaving the cursor inside the file beyond what `tail` is meant to select.

So, you could use a tool that reads one character at a time like the shell's `read` (here using a function that takes the number of head lines and tail lines as arguments).

```
head_tail() {
  n=0
  while [ "$n" -lt "$1" ]; do
    IFS= read -r line || { printf %s "$line"; break; }
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    n=$(($n + 1))
  done
  tail -n "${2-$1}"
}
seq 100 | head_tail 5 10
seq 20 | head_tail 5
```

or implement `tail` in awk for instance as:

```
head_tail() {
  awk -v h="$1" -v t="${2-$1}" '
    {l[NR%t]=$0}
    NR<=h
    END{
      n=NR-t+1
      if(n <= h) n = h+1
      for (;n<=NR;n++) print l[n%t]
    }'
}
```

With `sed`:

```
head_tail() {
  sed -e "1,${1}b" -e :1 -e "$(($1+${2-$1})),\$!{N;b1" -e '}' -e 'N;D'
}
```

(though beware that some `sed` implementations have a low limitation on the size of their pattern space, so would fail for big values of the number of tail lines).

Answer (score 6):

With the `-u` (`--unbuffered`) option of GNU `sed`, you can use `sed -u 2q` as an unbuffered alternative to `head -n2`:

```
$ seq 100|(sed -u 2q;tail -n2)
1
2
99
100
```

When `(head -n2;tail -n2)` is used in a pipeline, it doesn't print the last lines when the last lines are part of a block of input that is consumed by `head`:

```
$ seq 1000|(head -n2;tail -n2)
1
2
999
1000
$ seq 100|(head -n2;tail -n2)
1
2
```

If the input is a regular file and not a pipeline, you can just use `(head -n2;tail -n2)`:

```
$ seq 100 >a;(head -n2;tail -n2)<a
1
2
99
100
```

Comment: this should be the top answer! works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

Using `bash` process substitution, you can do the following:

```
make_some_output | tee >(tail -n 2) >(head -n 2; cat >/dev/null) >/dev/null
```

Note that the lines are not guaranteed to be in order, though for files longer than about 8kB, they very likely will be.  This 8kB cutoff is the typical size of the read buffer, and is related to the reason `| {head; tail;}` doesn't work for small files.

The `cat >/dev/null` is necessary to keep the `head` pipeline alive.  Otherwise `tee` will quit early, and while you'll get output from `tail`, it'll be from somewhere in the middle of the input, rather than the end.

Finally, why the `>/dev/null` instead of, say, moving `tail` to another `|`?  In the following case:

```
make_some_output | tee >(head -n 2; cat >/dev/null) | tail -n 2  # doesn't work
```

`head`'s stdout is fed into the pipe to `tail` rather than the console, which isn't what we want at all.

Comment: When head or tail finish writing the output they want, they close their stdin and exit. That's where the SIGPIPE is coming from. Normally this is a good thing, they're discarding the rest of the output, so there is no reason for the other side of the pipe to continue spending time generating it.

Comment: What makes the order likely to be upheld? It probably will be for a large file, because `tail` has to work longer, but I expect (and do see) it failing about half the time for short inputs.

Comment: You'll get the SIGPIPE with `tee >(head) >(tail)` for the same reasons (`>(...)` which by the way is a ksh feature now supported by both zsh and bash as well) uses pipes as well. You could do `... | (trap '' PIPE; tee >(head) >(tail) > /dev/null)` but you'll still see some _broken pipes_ error messages from `tee`.

Comment: On my system (bash 4.2.37, coreutils 8.13), **`tail`** is the one being killed by SIGPIPE, not **`tee`**, and `tail` isn't writing to a pipe.  So it must be from a `kill()`, right?.  And this only happens when I'm using the `|` syntax.  `strace` says that `tee` isn't calling `kill()`... so maybe `bash`?

Comment: @Stephane - I've never seen the SIGPIPE with the `>(head) >(tail)` syntax.  I always do with the `|` syntax.

Comment: @Jander, try feeding more than 8k like `seq 100000 | tee >(head -n1) >(tail -n1) > /dev/null`

Comment: @Stephane -- Ah, in that case `tee` quits early, SIGPIPE is sent to `seq`, and `tail` prints what from its view is the last line of the stream... in my case, 2679.  But I finally understand why `tail` was getting a SIGPIPE... its output was being fed into `head` along with `tee`'s.  I've updated my answer -- thanks a lot for the debugging help!

Comment: Note that with `seq 3 | ...`, line 2 will be output twice which may or may not be desirable, I've taken special care to avoid it in the solution I gave.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ed` (which will read the entire file into RAM though):

```
# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed
printf '%s\n' 'H' '1,10p' '$-10,$p' 'q' | ed -s file
```

Comment: Shorter: `ed -s file <<< $'11,$-10d\n,p\nq\n'`

Answer (score 2):

Stephane's first solution in a function so that you can use arguments (works in any Bourne-like or POSIX shell):

```
head_tail() {
    head "$@";
    tail "$@";
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
head_tail -n 5 < /path/to/file
```

This of course assumes that you're looking at only one file and like Stephane's solution works (reliably) only on regular (seekable) files.

Answer (score 1):

You may try Perl, if you have it installed:

```
perl -e '@_ = <>; @_=@_[0, -3..-1]; print @_'
```

This will work for most files, but reads the whole file into memory before processing it. If you're not familiar with Perl slices, "0" in square brackets means "take the first line", and "-3...-1" means "take last three lines". You may tailor both of them to your needs. If you need to process really large files (what is 'large' may depend on your RAM and perhaps swap sizes), you may want to go for:

```
perl -e 'while($_=<>){@_=(@_,$_)[0,-3..-1]}; print @_'
```

it may be somewhat slower, because it makes a slice every iteration, but it's independent on the file size.

Both commands should work both in pipes and with regular files.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something like this today where I needed only the last line and a few lines from the front of a stream and came up with the following.

```
sed -n -e '1{h}' -e '2,3{H}' -e '${H;x;p}'
```

I read this as: initialize the hold space with the contents of the first line, append lines 2-3 in the hold space, at EOF append the last line to the hold space, swap hold-and-pattern space, and print the pattern space.

Perhaps someone with more `sed`-fu than I have can figure out how to generalize this to print the last **few** lines of the stream indicated in this question but I didn't need it and could not find an easy way to do math based on the `$` address in `sed` or perhaps by managing the hold space so that only the last few lines are in it when `EOF` is reached.

Comment: This is basically the same as `sed -n '1,3p;$p'`.