# Combing head and tail in a single call via pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, tail, head

On a regular basis, I am piping the output of some program to either `head` or `tail`.

Now, suppose that I want to see the first AND last 10 lines of piped output, such that I could do something like

```
 ./lotsofoutput | headtail
```

I am specifically looking for an easy to remember, simple and elegant solution.

Closest I got was

```
 ./lotsofoutput | sed -n -e '1,10p' -e 'N,$p'
```

Or, by means of [Command to display first few and last few lines of a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48777/command-to-display-first-few-and-last-few-lines-of-a-file)

```
headtail is a function
headtail () 
{ 
    head -n 3 -- "$1";
    tail -n 3 -- "$1"
}
$ echo {1..10} | tr " " "\n" | headtail -
1
2
3
$
```