# How to get the recent time updated row using linux?

Tags: linux, text-processing

---

The following table is the mysql database table(i.e select * from users)
I want the last updated time  row  using linux command?

```
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+--------+------+--------------+
| time       | userid   | groupid | jobs_running | jobs_pending | job_limit | 
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+--------+------+--------------+
| 1476274005 | achandra |         |            4 |            0 |         0 |            
| 1476274793 | akawle   |         |           52 |           48 |         0 |     
| 1476274793 | awle     |         |           56 |           49 |         0 |    
| 1476274799 | awlnbkle |         |           59 |           67 |         0 |
```

Expected Output:

```
| 1476274793 | akawle   |         |           52 |           48 |         0 |     
| 1476274793 | awle     |         |           56 |           49 |         0 |    
| 1476274799 | awlnbkle |         |           59 |           67 |         0 |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48777/command-to-display-first-few-and-last-few-lines-of-a-file

Comment: Your edit is nice, but how do you determine the number of rows to output ? Do you compare the  `time` column value with a reference ? Do you want those rows to be printed in terminal dynamically (everytime the table is appended) or to be able to run a command once in a while to extract those values ?

Comment: Also you should add the `/text-processing` tag in your next edit.

Comment: Rows to printed dynamically when the table is appended everytime.I had used (i.e $current_time=`date +%s`).But this does not shows my expect output because it display all timings .But i need the last recent updated time which i mentioned in the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -n 1 input.txt
```

Check `man tail` for more detail on the command. This command simply displays the last line of the file.

---

**EDIT** 
Considering the information you added, you might to try this:

```
tail -f -n 0 input_file.txt
```

The `-f` (for *follow*) means that everytime some data is added in `input_file.txt`, it will be outputed to the terminal where you are running that command. `-n 0` is here so that when you run the command, you display nothing and only consecutive appended lines will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_command | sort -rn | head -n 1
```

Since the most recent time must be the maximum value

If your_command is mysql, you should also use -B for it, in order to obtain tab seperated output instead of bars.